# Accessing Mac OSX MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I just recently found out that OSX has a way of installing a PHP development server without XAMPP. However, does it also include MySQL?

This is all for Laravel. I'm now trying to connect to a database but can't.

Comment: No. MySQL is not preinstalled

Comment: You can install it through [official release](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) or through commandline utilities like [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Anyhow, **read careful** configuration options